# Return min Index Recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int f(int a[], int size) {
    if (size == 1)
        return arr[0];
    size--;
    return f((arr + (arr[0] > a[size])), size);
}
```

I'm attempting to return the index of the minimum. The code above returns the VALUE of the minimum, but I'm having trouble returning the index, can anyone help? Also, I'm only allowed to pass 2 parameters to the function, the array and the size of the array.

Comment: What language is this? C? C++?

Comment: If the function is in C or C++ (or any language based on C or C++) then you can't really return multiple values. You can "return" it as an *output* parameter, or by using a *pair* or *tuple* or *structure* or even an *array* (in some languages) as return value. Exactly how to do that is depending on your language which we know nothing about.

Comment: Or wait, do you want to change the function to *only* return the index, and not the value?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I read it as he wants only the index, but worst case scenario the calling function still has the array and can just retrieve the value using the array and the index.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just need the index.

Comment: @Paul Hey Paul, this is C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code below (modified to use 2 parameters only):

```
int f(int a[], int size) {
    if (size <= 1)
        return 0;
    int i = f(a, --size);
    return a[size] < a[i] ? size : i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rbaghbanli, this definitely helps. Is there a way to do this with only  passing 2 parameters to the function, the array and the size of the array?

Comment: Sure, modified to use 2 parameters only.

Comment: This did it! Thank you SOOOO much @rbaghbanli

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will probably work:

```
size_t f(int a[], size_t low_index, size_t high_index) {
    if (low_index == high_index) {
        return low_index;
    }

    if (arr[low_index] > arr[high_index]) {
        low_index++;
    } else {
        high_index--;
    }

    return f(a, low_index, high_index);
}
```

You'd call it with `f(a, 0, size-1)`.

That said, I'm not sure why you want to do this recursively when it seems easier to do it in a for loop:

```
size_t f(int a[], size_t size) {
    size_t min_index = 0;
    int min_value = a[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (a[i] < min_value) {
            min_value = a[i];
            min_index = i;
        }
    }

    return min_index;
}
```